# Why is NSSpeechSynthesizer outputting empty files on OS X? (Swift 2)

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, text-to-speech, swift2

I'm using Xcode 7 (beta 5) and Swift 2.0 on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.4

Whenever I attempt to use the "startSpeakingString:toURL:" function, the files exist but are empty. (The duration is "--" and the size is "zero bytes") The function "startSpeakingString:" does work, however, and the audio is played as expected.

I have tried to change the "volume" and the "rate" variables, and I have tried using something like "usleep" to make sure that the process is not interrupted.

Initialization:

```
let mySynth: NSSpeechSynthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer(voice: NSSpeechSynthesizer.defaultVoice())!
let dirs : [String] = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as [String])
```

Use:

```
let documentsDir = dirs[0]
let audioDir = documentsDir.stringByAppendingString("/temp.aiff")
let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(audioDir)
mySynth.startSpeakingString("Testing some more", toURL: audioURL)
```

I thought this might have something to do with Swift 2.0 not supporting "String.stringByAppendingPathComponent", but the complete path prints out exactly the same using the new function. I have also considered using a different file extension in place of ".aiff", but I cannot find any documentation which specifies a new format.

I did have this working at an earlier point in the project, but I have been unable to pinpoint what caused it to break. I have tried using a project backup that was written for Swift 1.2 with no results.

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? If so, this might be a sandbox violation.

Comment: My app is not sandboxed according to the Resource Monitor. Additionally, if sandboxing was the problem, then the database I create in another part of the app would not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what was causing the problem, but it is fixed now. There was an update for OS X that seemed to fix the issue. I am now running OS X 10.10.5 and the program works perfect.

Thanks to [Aderstedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453082/aderstedt) and [Eric D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-d) for the suggestions.

If anyone else runs into this issue and finds a different solution, please leave a comment or answer, as I'd be interested in another solution.

Comment: I'm running into this on 10.15.5, but only after I've already output maybe a few hundred files. It doesn't seem built for such heavy use.

`speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool)`

is called, with `didFinishSpeaking` set to true, but the file is empty. Even after restarting my app, I can't create more files until I quit the speech synthesis processes in Activity Monitor. There's also a limit to how many NSSpeechSynthesizer objects can exist at once before init starts returning nil, so be sure to deallocate them!

Comment: I don't seem to be able to edit my comment, but I'd just like to add some precision: After writing around 2200 files, I can't create any more until I quit the  com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd process.